# AVR - AT90CAN128, random jump to code

Tags: c, memcpy, avr-gcc

Because i use tabs instead of spaces, the code is available here:
http://pastebin.com/ff3m5Cwv

The problem:

In the main, the chip jumps from the first renderTimeTable() call in the main, to memcpy after the blocking while.
Anything involving copying spi_buffer array to portbuffer array causes the issue

am i calling the function wrong?

this issue started occuring after i started using memcpy

i am using avr studio 4

Comment: Notepad++ has a "convert tabs to spaces" feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
      uint8_t portbuffer[8];
      memcpy((void*) spi_buffer, portbuffer,8);
```

The first parameter in `memcpy` is the destination, not the source. You are using it the opposite way.

Comment: Ok, i changed that, but the bug is still happening